# How do you notate vocables?

Tags: notation, voice, lyrics

Is it the same way as notating regular lyrics? Some of the vocables I would like to use are "ah" and "ooh".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, exactly the same.  This is true for sheet music:

[image]

Chord/lyric sheets:

[image]

As well as tabs and other forms.

Comment: Thank you! I'm more talking about long stretches of a single syllable. I assume it's still the same though.

Comment: @isaac.mailach Yep, same thing.